# Move review tab on product page

Tags: layout, review, tabs, product-page

### How do I move the review tab on the product page?

The code to generate the tabs is found in `app/design/frontend/example/shop/template/catalog/product/view.phtml`

```
<div id="tabs" class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
        <?php if ($detailedInfoGroup = $this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
            <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                <?php foreach ($detailedInfoGroup as $alias => $html):?>
                    <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt>
                    <dd class="tab-container">
                        <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

**It currently looks like so:**

[image]

**this is what I'd like to achieve:**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this way:

Go to your `theme/layout/review.xml`.

Now, find

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml" after="additional">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

and change `<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>` to

```
<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>review_info</group></action>
```

**See we are just replacing `detailed_info` to `review_info`.**

Then go to your `theme/template/catalog/view.phtml` and add following code after that `description` code:

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
        <?php if ($review = $this->getChildGroup('review_info', 'getChildHtml')):?>
            <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                <?php foreach ($review as $alias => $html):?>
                    <dt class="tab"><span><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getChildData($alias, 'title')) ?></span></dt> 
                    <dd class="tab-container">
                        <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $html ?></div>
                    </dd>
                <?php endforeach;?>
            </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
```

I haven't tested, but should work.

Good luck.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. Please go through it once more :)

Comment: I am sure, I have understood his qst.

Comment: Yup you are right. I was the one who misinterpreted the question. I didnt see the review tab in bottom side. oops.. lol... :)

Comment: No worries Rajeev... Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

File : `app\deisign\frontend\<your_package>\<your_theme>\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <remove name="product.reviews" />
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

### EDIT - 1

Please note this will remove review tab entirely from the product view page. I misinterpreted your question. I am leaving this answer for downvoting. Coz there is a chance to happen same misinterpretation that I had to some others. I dont want to happen and that's it.Thanks.

### EDIT - 2 : To Suit to this particular question

Adharsh answer will work. Here is another approach...

**Step - 1**

File : `app\deisign\frontend\<your_package>\<your_theme>\layout\local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <remove name="product.reviews" />
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="core/template" name="review_wrapper" as="review_wrapper" template="custom/review/catalog/product/wrapper.phtml">
                <block type="review/product_view_list" name="product.reviews" as="reviews" template="review/product/view/list.phtml"></block>
                <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Reviews</value></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Here first we removed entire `review` block. This will remove review block from the tabs section. Then we added a new `core/template` block and re-declared the review block inside it. Thus `core/template` block is just wrapper for `review` block which is set with a fresh template `wrapper.phtml`

**Step - 2**

File : `app\design\frontend\<your_package>\<your_theme>\template\catalog\product\view.phtml`

```
 <div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
    ....
 </div>

  <!-- calling wrapper block just after the tabs section -->
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_wrapper') ?>
```

Here we just call our new wrapper block inside product view template.

**Step - 3**

File : `app\design\frontend\<your_package>\<your_theme>\template\custom/review/catalog/product/wrapper.phtml`

```
<div class="product-collateral toggle-content tabs">
        <dl id="collateral-tabs" class="collateral-tabs">
                <dt class="tab">
                    <span><?php echo $this->getTitle() ?></span>
                </dt>
                <dd class="tab-container">
                    <div class="tab-content"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('reviews') ?></div>
                </dd>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </dl>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

and that's it.

There are lot of solutions to do the same. We can do this programmatically too. But I love the layout way.. that is perfect in this case.

---

**Note 1** : dont use very first layout update. it is wrong. Answer lies in the second edit.

**Note 2**: Didn't test this. Should work

Comment: You should remove or edit your answer rather than waiting for other to down vote. Like your ethics though.

Comment: you think so.. I will not remove this answer, rather gonna put another solution. :-)

Comment: If you didn't test it and you are not sure if will work then you shouldn't post this. Not helpful.

Comment: @JoãoMachete Be honest,We are not here to provide the community with a bullet proof solution which works in a blink, rather educate the community to solve the issues theme self from the given answer. If you are here to get a well tested "copy pasted - Bingo it works!!" solution, then you misunderstood how the stack exchange works.